# Jquery Datatable not updating table after adding new record,using in Angular4 application

Tags: jquery, angular, datatable

I'm using Jquery datatable in Angular4 application everything is working fine except data updating issue.I am doing like this to do table update:

```
if(data.status == 'success'){
   this.dataArr.push({ 
                      "dept_name": value.deptName, 
                      "created_by": this.loginEmpDetails.empId, 
                      "created_date": new Date(), 
                      "updated_by": null, 
                      "updated_date": null, 
                      "dept_status": 1 });
   var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
   table.draw()
}
```

If anyone faced this problem please help me out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have to use the datatable jquery plugin? Because there are some many data table components from other libraries that don't use jQuery. If you can avoid jQuery do it, specially in angular apps

Comment: Use https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started